# SharePoint Calculated Field Formula

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I keep getting an error on the following, where am I going wrong?

=IF(AND([status_pr]=”approved”,[status_sr]=”approved”,[status_dr]=”approved”),“Submission Approved”,IF(AND([status_pr]=”approved”,[status_sr]=”approved”,[status_dr]=”pending”), “Solution/Delivery Approved”,IF(AND([status_pr]=”approved”,[status_sr]=”pending”,[status_dr]=”pending”),“Pursuit Approved”,”Pending”)))

Comment: Have you resolved it? If yes, "accept" the helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You AND operator has three operands like AND(X,Y,Z).
Try changing that to AND(AND(X,Y),Z)

Comment: not sure I follow?

Comment: =IF(AND([status_pr]=”approved”,
AND([status_sr]=”approved”,[status_dr]=”approved”)),“Submission Approved”,IF(AND([status_pr]=”approved”,
AND([status_sr]=”approved”,[status_dr]=”pending”)), “Solution/Delivery Approved”,IF(AND([status_pr]=”approved”,AND([status_sr]=”pending”,[status_dr]=”pending”)),“Pursuit Approved”,”Pending”)))

Comment: Try this. =IF(AND([status_pr]=”approved”,
AND([status_sr]=”approved”,[status_dr]=”approved”)),“Submission Approved”,IF(AND([status_pr]=”approved”,
AND([status_sr]=”approved”,[status_dr]=”pending”)), “Solution/Delivery Approved”,IF(AND([status_pr]=”approved”,AND([status_sr]=”pending”,[status_dr]=”pending”)),“Pursuit Approved”,”Pending”)))

Comment: got the classic something went wrong with 

=IF(AND([status_pr]=”approved”, AND([status_sr]=”approved”,[status_dr]=”approved”)),“Submission Approved”,IF(AND([status_pr]=”approved”, AND([status_sr]=”approved”,[status_dr]=”pending”)), “Solution/Delivery Approved”,IF(AND([status_pr]=”approved”,AND([status_sr]=”pending”,[status_dr]=”pending”)),“Pursuit Approved”,”Pending”)))

Comment: You have multiple triple and which is not valid. Fix all 3

Comment: not sure what you mean by multiple triple

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are using the wrong double quotation mark (`”`).

Change it to `"`

```
=IF(AND([status_pr]= "approved",[status_sr]= "approved",[status_dr]= "approved"),"Submission Approved",IF(AND([status_pr]= "approved",[status_sr]= "approved",[status_dr]= "pending"), "Solution/Delivery Approved",IF(AND([status_pr]= "approved",[status_sr]= "pending",[status_dr]= "pending"),"Pursuit Approved","Pending")))
```